# How to automatically draw the edge between two regions in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I have an image that has areas with different colors in them similar to this

[image]

I would like to draw a line at the boundary between the red and the blue regions using Gimp. So the end result might look something like this

[image]

I can select one of the two regions with the Select by Color Tool, but then I don't know how to draw the edge of the selection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Choose black as the foreground colour

[image]

2. Select the Brush Tool. In the tool options underneath the toolbox, set the Hardness to 100%, and size to something like 10.

[image]

3. Use the Fuzzy select tool (Magic Wand) or the Select by Colour tool, to select the blue area
4. Do *Edit > Stroke selection*, choose the "*Stroke with a paint tool*" option. Click *Stroke*.
5. Do *Select > None* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

Example:

[image]