# Gimp: Extend Background with Colour Gradient

Tags: gimp, gradient, background

I would like to extend an image like this

[image]

to the left and to the top with GIMP. I just do not seem to find quite the fitting gradient.

This image is an example as a background. In the original there are further elements in the picture.

Is there a step by step walkthrough to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you recreate the gradient. It's probably easier than trying to extend or squish/stretch the existing image, and the results will be better anyway.

1. Click on the foreground colour square, and when the change colour dialog opens, sample the colours from the original image using the eyedropper button in the dialog
2. When you sample each colour, hit the arrow button in the dialog, to add them to the colour history to store them. I sampled 6 here, although you could do more

[image]

3. Switch to the Gradient tool, set it to Radial in the tool options using any colour gradient. Click and drag to draw a gradient on the canvas
4. Edit the on-screen gradient to make a custom gradient using the sampled colours for your stops. You can add stops by clicking on the gradient line, select a stop and change its colour using the colour selector (in the little panel shown top right). You can click and drag the stops to adjust their position to make the gradient nice and smooth. A little trial and error may be required here.

[image]

5. Finally create a new blank document the size you want, and apply the gradient to it.

Comment: So, would you crop the foreground object, create a whole new background, and eventually paste the foreground object?

Comment: @Yahalnaut  what foreground object? Do you mean the text in the corner?

Comment: The given image is just a placeholder for an image with foreground objects and a background with gradient colour.

Comment: @Yahalnaut If you have an image where you want to separate the background from the foreground objects, then no. This can't be achieved by using the crop tool.  You could use the Foreground Select tool in GIMP to create a mask perhaps.  This is really an entirely different question, and not related to the answer I gave here at all, since I based it on the example image you provided.  Perhaps look up some tutorials on using the Foreground Select tool.

Comment: In fact there's [an answer here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/135037/89608) I posted here which covers the basic operation of the Foreground Select tool.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a comment seems to be forbidden. But writing the same as an answer is possible. The moderator hopefully turns this a comment.

You obviously have a single layer bitmap image. A remarkable part of the image area is covered by a gradient. There's also other shapes in the same layer, so suggestion "make a new gradient background" is practically useless. You want to enlarge the canvas size and fill the new area with a gradient which joins seamlessly to the original gradient. Seamlessly means that all color factors change continuously over the original image edge with no abrupt rate changes.

That's a non-trivial mathematical problem and probably beyond the capabilities of 99.9% of the people who visit here (including me). But someone claims he has solved it and he has written his method as GIMP script. Check it yourself https://sourceforge.net/p/gimp-g-e/wiki/Home/